# Why is <ui:fragment rendered> not evaluated on <h:outputStylesheet> and <h:outputScript>

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, conditional-rendering

I have a JSF 2 master template as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="#{localeManager.language}" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <f:view locale="#{localeManager.locale}">
        <h:head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title.</ui:insert></title>

            <!-- Development Stylesheets -->
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Development'}">
                <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.css" library="bootstrap" />
                <h:outputStylesheet name="css/font-awesome.css" library="fontawesome" />
            </ui:fragment>

            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/main.css" library="core" />
            <ui:insert name="header-stylesheet" />

            <!-- Production Stylesheets -->
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Production'}">
                <h:outputStylesheet name="css/bootstrap.min.css" library="bootstrap" />
                <h:outputStylesheet name="css/font-awesome.min.css" library="fontawesome" />
            </ui:fragment>

            <ui:insert name="header-script" />
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="header">
                    <ui:insert name="header">Default content</ui:insert>
                </div>

                <div id="body">
                    <ui:insert name="body">Default body</ui:insert>
                </div>

                <div id="footer">
                    <ui:insert name="footer">Default footer</ui:insert>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Development Scripts -->
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Development'}">
                <h:outputScript name="jquery-2.1.4.js" library="jquery" />
                <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.js" library="bootstrap" />
            </ui:fragment>

            <!-- Production Scripts -->
            <ui:fragment rendered="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Production'}">
                <h:outputScript name="jquery-2.1.4.min.js" library="jquery" />
                <h:outputScript name="js/bootstrap.min.js" library="bootstrap" />
            </ui:fragment>
            <ui:insert name="body-script" />
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

When deploying it in Wildfly 9.0.1 Final, I see that all my `<ui:fragment>` attribute gets rendered. Why is that? I am developing using JSF 2.2 framework.

My Faces Project stage is `Development`.

*Note:* Of all the answers in SO concerning this issue, none is the solution to this problem (so I did my homework).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>` are special components. They will during view build time already add the declared stylesheet or script resource to the view via [`UIViewRoot#addComponentResource()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/4.0/apidocs/jakarta/faces/component/uiviewroot#addComponentResource(jakarta.faces.context.FacesContext,jakarta.faces.component.UIComponent)) ([see Mojarra source code here](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mojarra/blob/4.0.4-RELEASE/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/ScriptStyleBaseRenderer.java)).

This is regardless of the `rendered` condition of the component or its parents. In effects, they are basically relocated to the very end of the `<h:head>` or the `<h:body>`, depending on the value of `target` attribute, causing them to not sit inside `<ui:fragment>` anymore.

Then, during rendering, only their own `rendered` attribute is considered (and actually also of `<h:head>`, but that's pointless).

You have 2 options:

1. Use a view build time tag to conditionally add them to the view. The project stage condition is application scoped anyway.

   ```
    <!-- Development Stylesheets -->
    <c:if test="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Development'}">
        <h:outputStylesheet ... />
        <h:outputStylesheet ... />
    </c:if>

    <!-- Production Stylesheets -->
    <c:if test="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Production'}">
        <h:outputStylesheet ... />
        <h:outputStylesheet ... />
    </c:if>
   ```
2. Check the condition in component resource's own `rendered` attribute. Use if necessary `<c:set>` to create a short EL variable.

   ```
    <c:set var="dev" value="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Development'}" scope="application" />

    <!-- Development Stylesheets -->
    <h:outputStylesheet ... rendered="#{dev}" />
    <h:outputStylesheet ... rendered="#{dev}" />

    <!-- Production Stylesheets -->
    <h:outputStylesheet ... rendered="#{not dev}" />
    <h:outputStylesheet ... rendered="#{not dev}" />
   ```

#### See also:

- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: So, if I use JSTL conditional `if`, shouldn't I use the `$` instead of `#`?

Comment: You can, but that's not uniform and unnecessarily confusing to starters. In Facelets, `${}` behaves exactly the same as `#{}`, but in JSP `${}` is immediately ("statically") evaluated while `#{}` is only evaluated on every call ("deferred").

Comment: Thanks. I got the stuff to work with JSTL conditional `if`.

Comment: Thanks too, i spend hours checking why my `ui:fragment` with rendered attribute around it did not worked.